# Why don't compiled bindings work with dependency properties, but classic bindings do?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I was trying to set up a binding from a `dependency property` in a custom control I wrote, and I noticed that the binding wasn't updating correctly. I should note that I'm just binding *from* the property.

The property is something pretty standard, like this:

```cs
public bool HasText
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(HasTextProperty);
    private set => SetValue(HasTextProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty HasTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(HasText), typeof(bool), typeof(TextEditor), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Now, I first tried with a compiled binding, which failed (it didn't show any errors, but it just wasn't working):

```xml
<controls:TextEditor x:Name="SomeTextEditor"/>
<controls:SomeControl IsEnabled="{x:Bind SomeTextEditor.HasText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Then I tried to use a classic binding, and this worked perfectly fine:

```xml
<controls:TextEditor x:Name="SomeTextEditor"/>
<controls:SomeControl IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SomeTextEditor, Path=HasText}"/>
```

Now, I have to say I'm not sure why this is happening. A `dependency property` has builtin support for notifications, otherwise the classic binding wouldn't be working either. And I didn't forget that the `x:Bind` defaults to `Mode=OneTime`, but even after manually setting it to `Mode=OneWay` it still wasn't working.

Any ideas? I might very well be missing something obvious here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At XAML compile time, [`{x:Bind}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) is converted into code that will get a value from a **property** on a data source, and set it on the **property** specified in markup.

The specified [`x:Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-name-attribute#remarks) becomes the name of a **field** that is created in the underlying code when XAML is processed, and that **field** holds a reference to the object.

If you use `x:Bind` to bind `x:Name` field, `IsEnabled` will not get available value just like the following code. That is the reason why the following does not work.

```
<controls:SomeControl IsEnabled="{x:Bind SomeTextEditor.HasText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that bindings can only work on properties and not on fields. I wonder why was the code still compiling though 